# SwiftUI NavigationSplitView link is disabled in compact mode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

When implementing my app, I want to embed a `NavigationStack` inside `NavigationSplitView`, as the documentation says. However, under compact mode like on iPhone, I encountered a bug.

To be specific, here's the example code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Link") {
                    NavigationStack {
                        Text("Destination")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            
        }
    }
}
```

When running the code above, as I tap the "Link", it navigate to "Destination" as expected. However, if I navigate back and tap again, this link won't navigate.

Is there any workaround? Thanks for your solution!

Comment: I don't think you should put a NavigationStack inside the `sidebar` of the NavigationSplitView

Checkout this session from WWDC22

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10054